# Filtering queries across $expands with WebApi2 OData

Tags: asp.net-web-api, odata

I have a WebApi 2.1 OData (v 5.1.1) service backed in Entity Framework 6.1. I'm trying to lock it down from a security standpoint, so that users can only query data that is theirs. I have everything working fine, until you get to the $expands option.

For the sake of this discussion, consider the following simplified data model:

```
public class Scenario
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public Guid CreatedById { get; set; }
}

public class Property
{
    public Guid Id { get; set }
    public Guid CreatedById { get; set; }
    public IQueryable<Scenario> Scenarios { get; set; }
}
```

When I call `/Properties(guid'SOMEGUID')?$expand=Scenarios`, I need to be able to make sure that only Scenarios where the CreatedById = CurrentUserId are returned. This needs to happen on the *server-side* and not in the client-side query.

WCF Data Services had QueryInterceptors that would handle this kind of situation... what is the equivalent in WebApi 2.1 OData?

Thanks!

Comment: Just so everyone who comes across this knows, the pattern Javier mentioned works, and we implemented it well in our product. However, https://github.com/OData/RESTier is a more comprehensive solution to this problem that stops traversal attacks in their tracks.

Answer (score 1):

here's a gist with a sample on how can you implement this on your own:
https://gist.github.com/anonymous/9237151

Based on my git, you can use a similar validator and implement your validation logic on a CanAcess method or similar. Let me know if this helps you.

We will have soon an official sample on http://aspnet.codeplex.com

Comment: Thank you so much for this, Javier. Is there an equivalent to IEdmNavigationSource in the EDM 5.6.1 library? Or can I just use IEdmNamedElement?

Comment: Javier, would you have a way to be able to use this technique to be able to limit the returned data where a property equals a specific value? (the equivalent of a left outer join?)

Answer (score -1):

There are two ways to solve your problem if I understood your question correctly.

1. Call the ApplyTo method of ODataQueryOptions on the IQueryable result
   `public IQueryable<Property> Get(ODataQueryOptions queryOptions)
   {
       ....
       return queryOptions.ApplyTo(properties);
   }`
2. Add attribute Queryable on the GetData method and let WebAPI handles the query option
   `[Queryable]
   public IQueryable<Property> Get()
   {
       ...
       return properties;
   }`

Comment: This is not what I'm looking for, I can already get the query and apply the options. I need to be able to limit the related data that comes back across navigation properties, and Javier's answer is correct.